# Redis: using two instances or just one (caching and storage)?

Tags: caching, redis

We need to perform rate limiting for requests to our `API`. We have a lot of web servers, and the rate limit should be shared between all of them. Also, the rate limit demands a certain amount of ephemeral storage (we want to store the users quota for a certain period of time).

We have a great rate limiting implementation that works with Redis by using `SETEX`. In this use case we need Redis to also be used a storage (for a short while, according to the expiration set on the `SETEX` calls). Also, the cache needs to be shared across all servers, and there is no way we could use something like an in-memory cache on each web server for dealing with the rate limiting since the rate limiting is per user - so we expect to have a lot of memory consumed for this purpose. So this process is a great use case for a Redis cluster.

Thing is - the same web server that performs the rate limit, also has some other caching needs. It fetches some stuff from a `DB`, and then caches the results in two layers: first, in an in-memory `LRU-cache` (on the actual server) and the second layer is Redis again - this time used as cache-only (no storage). In case the item gets evicted from the in-memory `LRU-cache`, it is passed on to be saved in Redis (so that even when a cache miss occurs in-memory, there would still be a cache-hit because thanks to Redis).

Should we use the same Redis instance for both needs (rate limiter that needs storage on one hand and cache layer that does not on the other)? I guess we could use a single Redis instance that includes storage (not the cache only option) and just use that for both needs? Would it be better, performance wise, for each server of ours to talk to two Redis instances - one that's used as cache-only and one that also features the storage option?

Comment: Divide and conquer is recommended - better performance and easier to scale.

Comment: Since the tasks are pretty different I would go for two different and independent redis servers/clusters.

Comment: what is the size of cache/storage you will need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always recommend dividing your setup into distinct data roles. Combining them sounds neat but in practice can be a real pain. In your case you ave two distinct "data roles": cached data and stored data. That is two major classes of distinction which means use two different instances.

In your particular case isolating them will be easier from an operational standpoint when things go wrong or need upgrading. You'll avoid intermingling services such that an issue in caching causes issues in your "storage" layer - or the inverse.

Redis usage tends to grow into more areas. If you get in the habit of dedicated Redis endpoints now you'll be better able to grow your usage in the future, as opposed to having to refactor and restructure into it when things get a bit rough.